# Null value select option not displaying in laravel/voyager

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, voyager

I am trying to create a select 2 option with the text "NA" with a value of "" in the select option however if the value is set to '' it doesnt render ( as evidenced in the image below, the NA option is missing.

If i were to remove the placeholder, the option will render just fine, how should i edit the code such that i can see the both the placeholder and the null value option?

```
    $dataType->addRows[$key]->display_name == "Service Provider")
<select 
id="service_provider_ID"
class = "form-control"
name = '{{$row->field}}'
data-name = '{{$row->display_name}}'
@if($row->required == 1) required @endif>
<option ></option>
    <option value="">NA</option>
    @foreach($all_service_providers as $service_providers){
        <option value = {{$service_providers->id}}> {{$service_providers->name}}</option>
    }
    @endforeach
</select>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#service_provider_ID').select2({
            placeholder:"Please select a Service Provider",
        });
        $('#client_name').select2({
            placeholder:"Please select a client",
        });
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, are you using any plugin for your select-box ?

Comment: @Swati select2, just edited the post to include more information

Comment: just remove `value=""` from here `<option value="">NA</option>` see if that works.